# What to do when two libraries insist on using the same namespace?

Tags: android, gradle, webrtc, aar

In my Android project I have 2 libraries that both rely on WebRTC. Both libraries do include WebRTC forcefully. Both libraries don't rename the WebRTC library (despite having customisations). Both developers insist WebRTC has to be forced-included this way (which I highly doubt).

*How do I solve this dependency conflict?*

I have already tried solutions like described here:
https://medium.com/mindorks/avoiding-conflicts-in-android-gradle-dependencies-28e4200ca235
But that specifically needs the dependencies to be transitive. Which hard-included libraries in my case are not. If I call `gradlew dependencies` WebRTC does not even show up on that list. But at compile time I get error like `Multiple dex files define Lorg/webrtc/VideoFileRenderer$2;` where "VideoFileRenderer" is a different file from org.webrtc each time I compile. Cleaning build tree or cache did not solve anything.

Libraries in question are:

- Ahoy-Conference : https://github.com/ahoyconference/cordova-ahoyrtc/tree/master/src/android/libs
- TokBox : https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/

Both libraries are never used at the same time at runtime. I only need to include both at compile time. Also each user only makes one video call at the registration to identify themselves.

Comment: I don't think there is anything you can do unless you can recompile those libraries.   You can use those providers (ahoy and tokbox) to use custom namespaces for WebRTC classes (f.e. com.ahoy.org.webrtc) when they build WebRTC so that there are no conflicts between them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is hard to believe that there is no other solution. After all, considering the amount of libraries out there, I can't be the first developer to come across this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude WebRTC for one of them

An example of exclusion from my project ( change names for your libs obviously )

```
  compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.9.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
```

Comment: The exclude command only works with transitive dependencies. Not with hard-coded ones.